# Bug with Two Range Series in one chart area with different YAxisType

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, range, mschart

I'm using .net 4, and have a chart with two range series on the same chart area, in different YAxisType

The chart, in one chart area, can't seem to work properly with these two ranged series. It gets confused, using the high value in the YAxisType of the series, and the low value in the other YAxisType.

[image: Observe that the black series, which is on the primary axis, is using the zero of the secondary Y-axis. In this case one of the secondary series is added first, by name order.]

Observe that the black series, which is on the primary axis, is using the zero of the secondary Y-axis. In this case one of the secondary series is added first, by name order.

[image: Now the situation is opposite. In this case the primary series is added first, by name order.]

Now the situation is opposite. In this case the primary series is added first, by name order.

All series are range with one of the values being 0.

Comment: You should really share some code and maybe a pic of what you have.

Comment: Check it out, added two images

Comment: So in MSChart all area series use the same baseline even if they are plotten in different y-axis? Maybe a limitation of MSChart. Ideally, an area chart should allow for specifying two series to use as high and low and shade in between.

Comment: Well, i suppose i would expect this behavior for area chart, but not from a range chart. It definitely looks like a limitation/bug.

Answer (score 0):

I thought i was using the Range type, but instead was using the Area one. Just made sure it was Range and it worked.